# Does XML AUTO support what I am trying to do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

At present we have a denormalised database. 
ie

```
Name|NameID|EmployeeID|EmployeeType
```

I'm normalising the database to resolve the EmployeeID from the Employee table rather than the  Name Table.

So we have a select at the moment

```
SELECT Name, NameID, EmployeeID, EmployeeType FROM Name 
FOR XML AUTO
```

Which will output:

```
 <Name Name='Fred' NameID='1' EmployeeID='1' EmployeeType='Manager'>
```

Now I have an INNER JOIN

```
SELECT Name, NameID, Name.EmployeeID, Employee.EmployeeType FROM Name
INNER JOIN Employee ON Name.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID
FOR XML AUTO
```

Now my XML looks like this:

```
<Name Name='Fred' NameID='1' EmployeeID='1'>
  <Employee EmployeeType='Manager' />
</Name>
```

My question is , is there any way to get XML AUTO to output my XML as before, or do i have to move to XML Explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `FOR XML PATH` instead?? It gives you a lot more control over the layout of your XML, and it's **A LOT EASIER** than XML EXPLICIT! :-)

```
SELECT 
   Name as '@Name', 
   NameID as '@NameID', 
   Name.EmployeeID as '@EmployeeID', 
   Employee.EmployeeType as '@EmployeeType'
FROM Name
INNER JOIN Employee ON Name.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID
FOR XML PATH('Name')
```

The `PATH('Name')` defines that the whole element should be a `<Name>` element, and if you use alias for your columns with a leading @ then you'll get attributes (without the leading "@", you get subelements).

Check out the MSDN article on [What's new in SQL Server 2005 XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137%28SQL.90%29.aspx) for some more details and examples.

Marc

Comment: I can, I would need to look up pros and cons of XML Explicit vs XML Path

Comment: :-) Just as I submitted my comment you updated your post to kindly include the link I need!

Comment: Cons: EXPLICIT is awfully complicated; PROS: FOR XML PATH is not :-) That's about all there is :-)